# meteor standalone app not working

Tags: node.js, meteor

I built my meteor app, with *meteor build  --directory*, then I did the npm install from the *programs/server* directory. I set

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://<mongo machine URL>:27017/<my db>
```

and

```
ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

Then, I start my app with *node main.js*. And the app looks like it starting. But when I try to connect to *http://localhost:3000* in the browser, I get nothing. When I try to curl that URL, I get:

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

I can't figure out what I could be missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure that `MONGO_URL` and `ROOT_URL` should be the same

Comment: they are not, I just didn't want to share that information, but it's the same value that I use when I run the meteor app with just "meteor" and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to set PORT=*wanted port*!